# ajax modelpopup

Tags: asp.net-ajax

model pop up show under control that have relative position and z-index small numbers like 1 10 100 in css and i cant change CSS for these controls any idea

Answer (score 0):

The modal popup has its own style. Just set its z-index to a high enough value to cover everything else on the page.

Comment: i try to put it from 1 to 9999999 here is the css for BackgroundCssClass     width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
 
    z-index: 99999 !important;